# TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function

Tags: deployment, solidity, chai, ethers.js, hardhat

I am getting this error while deploying my smart contract

```
const main = async() => {
  const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('TwitterContract');
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  //await contract.deployed();

  console.log("Contract deployed to: ", contract.address);
}

const runMain = async() => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

runMain();
```

this is the deploy.js script I am using to deploy my smart contract

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.15.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/contracts": "^5.7.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.2.0",
    "ethers": "^5.5.0"
  }
```

This are the dependencies

Answer (score 2):

I had the same bug for a while, what worked was upgrading from Ethers v5 to Ethers v6.6.2. so update your ethers version and I think it will work. you will have to make changes to your script though because ethers v6 comes with breaking changes. you should check the documentation.

To update just run `yarn add ethers` and it gets the latest version or if you want to install a specific version, you can do `yarn add ethers@6.6.2 <<where 6.6.2 is the version>>. You can do the same with` npm install ethers`and`npm install ethers@6.6.2`

Comment: In your answer it would be helpful if it was written how to update Ethers to the version, where this bug is resolved

Comment: okay, i will get to it

Answer (score -1):

So as swisscodemen said to solve this problem we need to update ethers version to V6, so go to your package.json file then find a line that looks like this one:

```
"ethers": "^5.6.7"
```

and then change to:

```
"ethers": "^6.0.0"
```

run `yarn` or `npm install` to update all dependencies